# Is it possible to calculate marginal effects on a ridge / lasso logistic regression model fit through glmnet?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, glmnet, marginal-effects

It seems like there is no support on applying the `margins` package to extract [average marginal effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Motivation) from a `glmnet` model. I am not able to replicate the same behaviour from `glm` as I'm fitting a ridge regression and (I think) the latter doesn't support this calculation. Is there any option to calculate marginal effects from a logistic ridge regression model?

Answer (score 0):

The development version of `marginaleffects` (soon to be published on CRAN as version 0.16.0) supports `tidymodels`. First, install the package:

```r
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

Then, restart `R` completely.

Finally, note that `glmnet` is only supported when the fit is specified via `tidymodels`’s formula interface (not the matrix form):

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(marginaleffects)

penguins <- modeldata::penguins |> na.omit()

mod <- linear_reg(mode = "regression", penalty = 1) |>
    set_engine("glmnet") |>
    fit(bill_length_mm ~ ., data = penguins)

avg_slopes(mod, newdata = penguins)
# 
#               Term           Contrast Estimate
#  bill_depth_mm     dY/dX               0.00000
#  bill_length_mm    dY/dX               0.00000
#  body_mass_g       dY/dX               0.00142
#  flipper_length_mm dY/dX               0.14098
#  island            Dream - Biscoe      0.00000
#  island            Torgersen - Biscoe  0.00000
#  sex               male - female       0.00000
#  species           Chinstrap - Adelie  5.35902
#  species           Gentoo - Adelie     0.00000
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, estimate 
# Type:  numeric
```